Agentive 'by phrase' included in passives: is it a complement? A modifier? Neither?
The committee was formed by him.

Is the 'by him' a complement or modifier?
And when does a 'by phrase' become modifier or complement?


Yᴏᴜʀ Qᴜᴇꜱᴛɪᴏɴꜱ Aʀᴇ Tᴏᴏ Sʜᴏʀᴛ: please put more effort into composing your questions, as it is unfair to expect others to put more effort into answering than you have put into asking. Tell us what led you to ask the question, such as some confusion or lack of clarity over some particular theory or model, what you think the answer may be, or why you question there even being a clear answer. What research into this matter did you do and where, and what in particular did you find there that seems unclear or conflicting to you? What is your own guess or guesses, and why do you think so?

It is not a complement, and much less a modifier. In a passive sentence the by-phrase is considered to be an adverbial, in the terminology of CoGEL. An adverbial is called an adjunct in some other grammars,  among them,  CGEL.
This particular adverbial  is of the process type (process adverbial). Process adverbials can be of 4 sorts: manner, means, instrument, agentive. A by-phrase is then a process adverbial of the agentive sort, where agentive has to be understood as refering to the agent, and not to the agentive, which is a semantic role assumed by the subject in an active sentence or the agent in a passive one.
CoGEL: A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language
CGEL: The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language
Additions suggested by comments

(CoGEL § 3.71) Agent constraints
Unlike the active subject, the agent by-phrase is generally optional. In fact approximately four out of five English passive sentences have no expressed agent. This omission occurs especially when the agent is irrelevant or unknown, as in:

The Prime Minister has often been criticized recently.

or where the agent is left out as redundant:

Jack fought Michael last night, and Jack was beaten.

An agent phrase by Michael would clearly not be necessary or even fully acceptable in this context.
Since the agent phrase is usually left unexpressed, the identity of the agent
may be irrecoverable, and it may be impossible to postulate a unique active
clause corresponding to the passive one […]
 Note
In some sentences, the agent is not optional; eg:
- The music was followed by a short interval. [1]
- *The music was followed. [2]
 - The rebels were actuated by both religious and political motives. [3]
- *The rebels were actuated. [4]

However, the nonoccurrence of the agentless sentences [2] and [4] may be due not so much to grammatical or lexical restriction, as to the fact that without the agent, the sentence becomes
informationally vacuous. (In this connection, [2] may be contrasted with We're being followed.)

I am not aware of the existence of a term for passive sentences with a mandatory agent by-phrase.

But some say that sometimes the by phrase is mandatory. When it is mandatory, what should we call it?

@Salimuddin I'll add some precisions on that.

@Salim Please give examples; it's often hard to validate unsourced claims.

Ah, LPH has added examples where the by-phrase is mandatory. Causative and sequencing verbs (though 'He was made/forced/compelled to wait' don't need a by-phrase). // 'Complement' is variously (and hence ill- unless a stipulative definition be imposed) defined. Some definitions would certainly class mandatory examples as containing complements.

'...[person] was survived by' / was characterised by' / 'was struck by' /  'was bordered by' / 'was preceded by' /  'was headed by' /  'was joined [?] by' (persons meeting) / 'was attended [?] by' / 'was conducted [?] by' /  'was influenced [?] by' / 'was greeted [?] by' / 'was complemented [?] by' / 'is exemplified [?] by' / are examples where the by-phrase is mandatory or rarely missing.

Sigh. An adjunct is a type of modifier in the Cambridge Grammar.

@EdwinAshworth Now added to the answer.


And when does a 'by phrase' become modifier or complement?

When it is locative:
His keys were found by the chair.
When it implies motion
The car was driven by the church.
In time phrases
He was finished by dinnertime
In relation to a circumstance:
Professionally, he was known by the name "Eric Jones".

OP obviously intends analysis to be confined to agentive by-phrases; this is all about the by-passive. I've edited accordingly.

Is this some ach riddle to make readers confused and sea sick? Q When is an animal a  mammal or a reptile?  A: When it is a rabbit, when it is a lizard and when it is a snake. I like it. Very avant gard!

@EdwinAshworth - (i) It wasn't at all obvious and (ii) I was, in any case answering the second part that, at the time, had not been addressed.
